# qcombobox does not update when currentIndexChanged is connected

Tags: qt, qwidget, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox on my gui that I use to select a string from a given set of options.

When I click on it the dropdown appears, I make my choice and then the dropdown closes again, but it's still the default value that is displayed and not the one that I selected.

The combo box is connected to a slot, so I know that the choice was made correctly. Only when I move the mouse over the combo it finally gets updated and shows the last choice made.

```
connect( _uiPtr->CB_PlotType, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(slotCurrPlotTypeChanged(int)) );
```

If  I comment this connection above, then the combo box is updated with new selection instantaneously.

The following link also describes the same problem but no solution:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18909-QComboBox-does-not-update

Comment: If you could provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem, that would be great.

Comment: Most likely, the `slotCurrPlotTypeChanged(int)` method does something to alter `CB_PlotType`'s state, perhaps indirectly. You likely have some sort of an update loop that should lock up your application, but Qt "helpfully" attempts to break such loops, and you end up wish misbehavior. Do any runtime warnings appear on the console. This is impossible to further debug without you providing a reproducable test case.

Comment: Did you try to use `comboBox->clear()` in your SLOT `slotCurrPlotTypeChanged(int)` ?

Comment: Its just an empty slot that I have defined which does nothing and still the issue